# Call a jQuery plugin function outside the Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have built a jQuery Plugin, but now I need to use one function from the Plugin outside of the Plugin.

The Plugin

```
(function ($) {
    jQuery.fn.vierGewinnt = function () {
 var VierGewinnt = function (config) {
            this.view = config.view;    
            this.dx;
            this.turn = 1;
        }
VierGewinnt.prototype.setToken = function (column) {
            for (var i = this.rows; i > 0; i--) {
                if (this.gamearray[column][i] == 0) {
                    this.gamearray[column][i] = "red";    
                    this.turn++;
                    this.findWinner(column, i);
                    break;
                }
            }

        }})(jQuery);
```

main.js I have tried:

```
$.setToken()
$.fn.vierGewinnt.setToken()
$.fn.vierGewinnt.VierGewinnt.setToken()
```

Maybe someone has a clue! Thx in advance!

Comment: How can that be working? I see no executable code. And there's a missing brace (`}`)

Comment: well...i left out a lot of code. because that was not really important ....and it does work! if I try $.fn.vierGewinnt it will show me the whole code of the plugin so I know that it is in the jquery prototype

Comment: Since it is defined inside a scope and then never exposed to something on the global scope, no there is no way for you to get access to it as-is.

Comment: That's good to know. Still you may want to fix the small mistakes even if it is an "example"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you have done it, you can't call it from outside.

There are a few patterns how you can make js/jquery widgets.

You are trying to combine the "normal" prototype with jQuery.

As I see you have two options.

1. Wrap you jQuery method to return the instance of the constructor. You can call prototype methods on it. Something like:

   ```
   $.fn.vierGewinnt = function(config){ 
       return new VierGewinnt (config); 
   };
   ```

   Then you can instance the plugin and call the method

   ```
   var plugin = $('#someSelector').vierGewinnt();
   plugin.setToken(column);
   ```

   In this case almost all your code can go outside the `(function ($)` block. You are just using jQuery as a wrapper, everything else is just ordinary javascript. As far as I can see your plugin is not called on any DOM element. It that case I don't see a lot sense in a jQuery plugin... it is pure javascript. If that is the case, just loose all the jQuery stuff from your example, and it will work.
2. Use a different plugin pattern. Personally I like the jQueryUI widget factory approach, but you will have to include jQueryUI for it. [Docs](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138135/Widget%20factory)

Answer (score 9):

All you need to do is return the function/plugin closure and create any methods you want to control outside the plugin as a property of the closure ($this).

```
    $.fn.vierGewinnt = function(options) {

        var $this = this;

        $this.setToken = function() {
            // setting token
        };

        return $this;
    };
```

And then save the reference to the plugin to call the method later.

```
    var vierPlugin = $('.some-element').vierGewinnt();
    vierPlugin.setToken(); // setting token outside plugin
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: Making the public setter functions return '$this':

```
this.setToken1 = function() {
  // setting token
  return $this;
};

this.setToken2 = function() {
  // setting token
  return $this;
};
```

allows using jQuery-style chaining:

```
vierPlugin.setToken1().setToken2();
```